# Client-side cannot locate socket.io.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've read all other posts on this topic but I cannot find answer for my problem. I have Express server running on default port or 5000 `(process.env.PORT || 5000)`. I then added socket.io but client-side cannot locate socket.io.js file. After some testings I assume that there is problem with some sort of port conflicts or something. Here is my server-side code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
```

Edit: Client-side stuff:[image]

Edit 2: Also, I don't think that it's important but I'm testing this on Heroku local.

Edit 3: Directory structure:

```
--api
--images
--node_modules
--scripts
--pages
    main_page.ejs
--styles
composer
index.js 
npm-debug
package
```

Edit 4: Bump

Comment: what are you considering `client-side`, the browser code?

Comment: want to add some client side code? what is the route the packets are taking? are your firewalls setup correctly?

Comment: I edited my question and added screenshot of client-side code/problem.

Comment: this is browser error. Please paste how you are trying to connect from front end?

Comment: @AsifSaeed You have that line of code as well, in the bottom of picture.

Comment: 404 means path not found. try changing the path or add your directory structure so we can suggest

Comment: And there you go, now down voting...

Comment: you should listen to the client-side

Comment: @Slay29 can you tell me a little about the directory structure and how you're serving your front end.

Comment: @DavidDiefenderfer Just a question, isn't point in socket.io to make it self serve files to client?

Comment: @Slay29 the point of it is to send and receive data via channels without having to hit a http endpoint everytime. 

I ran into something similar to the issue you're having a while back. But instead of putting up 20 things to try if you can share a little about the directory structure we can narrow this down and get you up and running

Comment: @DavidDiefenderfer I added it in edit.

Comment: If you add a copy of the `socket.io.js` into your scripts and load from there, does it fix the issue?

Comment: @DavidDiefenderfer I just tried that with user p0k8_ on TeamViewer and it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure it's saying that it's the file itself thats getting 404 and not the connection to backend? Is your index.html actually loading the socket.io.js file?

Comment: @DavidDiefenderfer I never said that. It's not loading, I also guess that it's connection error. Probably server not set up right.

Comment: I added the `socket.io` tag, because the `sockets` tag refers to the lower level socket layer, NOT to socket.io (which is a higher level implementation of some internet protocols, and NOT a low level socket).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Socket.IO is unable to intercept the requests to `/socket.io/` that load socket.io.js. This means that the virtual socket.io.js file is never loaded and you get the aforementioned 404 error.

## Solution

**Change this:**

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.listen(app.get('port', function() { ... });
```

**To this:**

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() { ... });
```

This prevents Express from immediately intercepting the requests to `/socket.io/` and allows the file to load.

Comment: Thank you on your answer. I have a question about this method. I use method app.listen(app.get('port'), function() { to tell app on what port to listen, but with your answer I cannot use app.get port because I didn't set up any. What is correct procedure for this?

Comment: Here's what you'll do: leave `app.set()` as you show in the above code. Then; instead of using `app.listen()` use `server.listen()`. I'll update my answer to show this.